# match format and return tokens from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to parse a large text using regex in PHP. I know the lines format, bellow shown using sprintf format, for ease of explaining.

So a line contains some known words (or parenthesis). I would like to know the matched format (in the example I printed the formats array key) and extract some relevant data out of the line.

I tried regex formats such as `'/(?<=new message from )(.*)(?=[)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=])/'`, but besides matching, I could not extract the correct data out of the lines.

```
$input = [
    'new message from Bob [22:105:3905:534]',
    'user Dylan posted a question in section General',
    'new message from Mary(gold) [19504:8728:18524:78941]'
];

$formats = [
    'new message from %s [%d:%d:%d:%d]', // this would actually be something like '/(?<=new message from )(.*)(?=[)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=])/'
    'user %s posted a question in section %s',
    'new message from %s(%s) [%d:%d:%d:%d]',
];

foreach ($input as $line) {
    foreach ($formats as $key => $format) {
        $data = [];
        if (preg_match($format, $line, $data)) {
            echo 'format: ' . $key . ', data: ' . var_export($data, true) . "\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
}

// should yield:
// format: 0, data: array ( 0 => 'Bob', 1 => 22, 2 => 105, 3 => 3905, 4 => 534, )
// format: 1, data: array ( 0 => 'Dylan', 1 => 'General', )
// format: 2, data: array ( 0 => 'Mary', 1 => 'gold', 2 => 19504, 3 => 8728, 4 => 18524, 5 => 78941, )
```

I need:

1. an efficient regex format, for matching a line, using multiple wildcards
2. a way to extract the wildcards, when a regex format matched a line (maybe the preg_match isnt the best regex php function to use in this case)

I can do this using string functions (strpos and substr), but the code looks awful..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little adjustment to the patterns. Please see the code below.

```
<?php

$input = [
    'new message from Bob [22:105:3905:534]',
    'user Dylan posted a question in section General with space',
    'new message from Mary(gold) [19504:8728:18524:78941]'
];

$formats = [
    '/new message from (\w+) \[(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\]/', // this would actually be something like '/(?<=new message from )(.*)(?=[)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=:)(.*)(?=])/'
    '/user (\w+) posted a question in section ([\w ]+)/',
    '/new message from (\w+)\((\w+)\) \[(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\]/',
];

foreach ($input as $line) {
    foreach ($formats as $key => $format) {
        $data = [];
        if (preg_match($format, $line, $data)) {                            
            array_shift($data); 
            echo 'format: ' . $key . ', data: ' . var_export($data, true) . "\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
}

// should yield:
// format: 0, data: array ( 0 => 'Bob', 1 => 22, 2 => 105, 3 => 3905, 4 => 534, )
// format: 1, data: array ( 0 => 'Dylan', 1 => 'General', )
// format: 2, data: array ( 0 => 'Mary', 1 => 'gold', 2 => 19504, 3 => 8728, 4 => 18524, 5 => 78941, )
```

https://3v4l.org/NBgaT

EDIT: I've added an `array_shift()` to get rid of the text that matched the full pattern.